# Call OpenAI API async with Python, asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, aiohttp, openai-api

I am trying to make asynchronous calls to openai API completions using aiohttp and asyncio. See below where I create a dataframe of elements (Door, Window, etc.) I want information from regarding the given context (description of a room)

```
#imports
import pandas as pd # Make a dataframe
import aiohttp  # for making API calls concurrently
import asyncio  # for running API calls concurrently

COMPLETIONS_MODEL = "text-davinci-003"
request_url =  "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"
request_header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"}

#data
prompt_list = ['Door', 'Window', 'Table']
init_context = " height if the room contains a door which is 8ft in height, a table 2ft in height and a window 6ft in height"

#dataframe of list of questions
q_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"type": prompt_list})

async def process_question(question: str, context: str):
    query = "What is the " + question + context
    data = {'model': 'text-davinci-003', 'prompt': f'{query}'}
    
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    async with session.post(url=request_url, headers=request_header, json=data) as response:
                        resp = await response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Request failed {e}")
    
async def process_questions(idf):
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[process_question(question, init_context) for question in idf['type']])
    
asyncio.create_task(process_questions(q_dataframe))
```

However I receive the following error for each request

```
Request failed Cannot connect to host api.openai.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')]
```

I tried using asyncio.sleep which didnt work. Am I using **asyncio.gather** incorrectly alongside **asyncio.create_task**?

I am able to run openai.completion.create on each dataframe row so my connection is fine

Comment: This is clearly a certificate problem. If you open the `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions` link in a browser and click on the padlock icon, you will see the certificate chain goes like this: ISRC Root X1 > R3 > api.openai.com. I once ran into a problem with the R3 cert having expired on Mac OS X Catalina (10.15). I downloaded the new R3 cert from Let's Encrypt and that fixed the problem

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm guessing Mac OS X

Comment: No i am using windows 10. I checked the certificate and it says it is valid

Comment: @CodeDifferent My chain is as follows ISRG Root X1 > R3 > api.openai.com

Comment: @CodeDifferent If it is any help I am running this via a Juypter Notebook v6.4.8 Python 3.9.12

Comment: I downloaded the .crt file (ISRG Root X1.crt) loaded it with: os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = '/data/ISRG Root X1.crt' and still not working

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `openai` [can be passed directly to session](https://github.com/openai/openai-python#async-api) for asynchronous execution. In conjunction with [ssl library](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets), the following can be written to handle this situation.

```py
import openai
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector
import ssl

ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(
    cafile=os.environ.get("REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE", None)
)
conn = TCPConnector(ssl_context=ssl_ctx)
session = ClientSession(connector=conn)
openai.aiosession.set(session)

chat_completion_resp = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])
...

# At the end of your program, close the http session
await openai.aiosession.get().close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an SSL certificate issue. You can try the following steps to fix it:

1. Update the Python package that provides the root certificates, which is called `certifi`:

```bash
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

2. Update the `aiohttp` library, if you haven't already:

```bash
pip install --upgrade aiohttp
```

3. You can bypass SSL verification by `ssl=False` as a last resort **(not recommended for production environments, as it could expose you to security risks)**:

```py
async def process_question(question: str, context: str):
    query = "What is the " + question + context
    data = {'model': 'text-davinci-003', 'prompt': f'{query}'}
    
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(url=request_url, headers=request_header, json=data, ssl=False) as response:
                resp = await response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Request failed {e}")
```